# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'

Tags: python, calculation

I want to calculate an expression which has "arctanh". I am getting the following error each time: "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64' ".

I tried to make the "w" as a complex number to avoid another error which was about producing nan by arctanh: "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in arctanh.

Thank you for any help or suggestion.

```
import numpy as np
e = np.arange (0.01,2000, 0.1)
w = [complex(i, 0) for i in e]
wtr = 10


etr_1 = (((1)/((np.pi*(np.power(w, 2)))+ np.pi))*(np.abs(((-2*np.arctan(wtr))*w)-(2*np.arctanh(((np.power(w, 2)) + 1)/(-1*(np.power(w, 2)) + 2*(np.power(wtr, 2)) +1))*(w))+ (np.pi*w) -(2*np.arctanh(w/(wtr))))))
```

Comment: You're trying to multiply incompatible types, e.g. `[1, 2] * 2.0` would produce that kind of error. Note that Python lists are not the same thing as numpy arrays. Try removing parts of your code and see where the problem is. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error because of this part  of your statement: `np.arctanh(w / (wtr))`. The reason for this is that w is a list of complex numbers and wtr is not. I'm not entirely sure of what you are trying to do. Therefore, I am not entirely sure how to correct the problem. Best of luck.